# PHP.ini Configuration

Tags: php, apache

I have just installed apache 2.2 with php 5.4.27 on xp sp3. everything runs fine. but when i configure php.ini my entire originally php code shows on the screen instead of running. don't know whats wrong with it. when i rename php.ini with php.ini-development my simple programs run smoothly but when i enable this file my entire original source code shows on the screen like this

```
   validate()) { $session = null; } } 
   catch (Exception $e) { $session = null; } 
} 
else { 
    try { $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect(); 
}
```

Comment: Check this variable: `short_open_tag=On`. Maybe you are using short tags, and in `php.ini` it's not enabled.

Comment: And also check the httpd.conf is there the `LoadModule php5_module "D:/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"` and `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php` Of course change the path of the `D:/PHP` where your PHP is.

Comment: Your snippet isn't valid code

Comment: Machavity, I suppose, the 'snippet' was used not to illustrate the code of an app, but to show that the author sees the code instead of the result of the code.

Comment: thanks for ur valuable and immediate reply. though i uncommented short_open_tag=on, its not working. everything is configured finely as per u suggest. i have revised my php.ini file many times yet unable to find out the actual bug behind. please do something.

Comment: now its working thanks. the problem was with TAG!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new php.ini, probably, disables usage of short PHP tags. If you start PHP code with **<?** instead of **<?php**, and short tags are disabled in the config, you won't get your script executed.

Check your php.ini file for **short_open_tag** and ensure this option is **On**.

Comment: oh my god its working man. i just replaced <? instead with <?php and everything is going fine. but what shall i do if i have to use short tags??

Comment: You just need to edit your php.ini, find there short_open_tag option, make it look short_open_tag=On and restart your Apache or php-fpm (I don't know which of them you use). After these steps you'll be able to use both short and normal tags in PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

1. Please ensure that PHP is enabled in apache, refer to the link below:

   http://editrocket.com/articles/php_apache_windows.html
2. Ensure that the php files end in the extention ".php" otherwise the server will not process it.
3. Is the php file inside your web directory?  PHP files will NOT be ran by apache if they are outside the specified web directory (such as htdocs)